# «Похуде́ние» или «похуда́ние»?

Tags: орфография, словообразование, стилистика

Как правильно: *похуде́ние* или *похуда́ние*?

Comment: См. также: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2757/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5