# "Похудение" и "похудание"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Мне кажется, что такого слова "похудание" нет, но тем не менее оно встречается и в речи, и даже в печатных текстах. Или все-таки такое слово есть?

Comment: Заголовок должен нести смысловую нагрузку. Заголовки типа "Как правильно?", "В чем ошибка?", "Как нужно писать/делать/говорить", "Что здесь неправильно?" подлежат обязательному исправлению! Иначе все заголовки будут (почти) одинаковыми. :)

Comment: См. также: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/397/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%95%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оба слова фиксируются словарями как нормативные. (Лопатин, например).
Мне кажется, что у них есть некоторые стилистические различия (похудение - некотролируемый процесс, похудание - сознательное действие, напрвленное на уменьшение массы тела), но не принципиальные.

Answer (score 1):

Похудеть - немного. Похудать, исхудать - стать болезненно худым. Надо думать о значении слова.

Answer (score 1):

Вот менение Грамоты:

> [Похудание и похудение](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti?layout=item&id=36_50)
>   Вопрос
>   Как правильно: средство для похудения или похудания?
>   Существительное похудение образовано от общеупотребительного глагола похудеть – стать худым, более худым; сделаться менее полным.
>   Существительное похудание образовано от разговорного глагола похудать  – то же, что похудеть.
>   Таким образом, **слова похудание и похудение различаются стилистически**. Похудание – разговорный вариант слова похудение. О средстве, которое помогает стать менее полным, правильно говорить средство для похудения.
>   Правильно
>   средство для похудения.

Answer (score 0):

В принципе, в русском просторечном языке есть слово "похудать", но все же "похудеть" и "похудение" - это гораздо правильнее и литературнее.