# Каково значение суффикса А в словах исхудать, похудание?

Tags: морфемика, суффиксы

Существуют два глагола: *похудеть и исхудать*. Исхудать ― это сильно похудеть. Вероятно, интенсивность действия задает приставка ИЗ, но почему *исхудать*, а не *исхудеть*?

Вопрос этот может быть связан со значением существительных *похудение и похудание.* В Сети, в том числе на этом форуме, активно обсуждались и обсуждаются эти вопросы, причем есть три варианта ответов: а) семантическое отличие, б) стилевое отличие, в) слово *похудание* ― просторечное или вообще ненормативное.

В то же время, если судить по примерам из Нацкорпуса, слово *похудание* с суффиксом А применяется в книжной речи, причем иногда в текстах, связанных с медициной. Очевидно, интенсивность процесса оно не обозначает, но тогда что оно обозначает?

Примеры:

1) Капитан уснул, а наутро обнаружил резкое **похудание** своих ног. [Дмитрий Липскеров. Последний сон разума (1999)]

2) Столь заметное **похудание** кошелька Тома Уокиншоу предопределило крупнейшую финансовую революцию этого сезона. [Пауль Ранге. Королевская бухгалтерия (2002) // «Формула», 2002.05.15]

3) По Аткинсу, **похудание** возможно на фоне потребления достаточно большого количества жира и белка и достаточно высокой калорийности рациона. [М. М. Гурвич. Модные и новомодные диеты // «Наука и жизнь», 2007]

Может быть, определение значения суффикса А поможет решить вопрос, связанный с семантикой и обоснованностью применения существительного *похудание*.

Обсуждение темы:

http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/3096912-pochemu-mnogie-govorjat-pohudanie-vmesto-pohudenie.html

http://kakimenno.ru/obrazovanie-i-nauka/srednee-obrazovanie/1552-kak-pravilno-pohudenie-ili-pohudanie.html

http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/2066361-chem-pohudenie-otlichaetsja-ot-pohudanija.html

["Похудение" и "похудание"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2757/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

["ПохудЕние" или "похудАние"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/397/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%95%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Глаголы с суффиксом -Е- наиболее продуктивно образуются от  сравнительной степени прилагательных, а степени сравнения имеют, как известно, качественные прилагательные. Полученные таким способом глаголы обозначают длительное становление состояния, нарастания качества, которого становится все больше по мере протекания этого процесса:

худеть - становиться худее

Для создания формы сов. вида используем приставки со значением «достичь результата, окончания процесса нарастания признака» Для глагола худеть видовая пара - похудеть, как утверждают словари.

похудеть - похудение (законченный процесс нарастания признака "худой")

похудать - просторечие, похудание - разговорное. Видимо, когда-то оба суффикса употреблялись, потом -е- стал предпочтителен.

Суффикс -А- унаследован из индоевропейского праязыка, где он тоже передавал идею длительности действия [Фортунатов, 1957, с.273], но  в целом словообразовательная модель "прилагательное + -А- "непродуктивна. 
http://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/suffiks-66812.html

Более или менее достоверные опростать (простой, то есть пустой) и корнать (корный, короткий). В современном русском языке таких глаголов, соотносительных с прилагательными, но допускающими и другую деривацию, больше. Они несут словообразовательное значение **«постепенно, длительно становиться таким, как указывает производящее прилагательное».** Таковы глаголы ветшать,  нищать, дичать, отмякать, дорожать, плошать, затихать,  серчать, крепчать, тончать, легчать, тощать, мельчать,  уменьшаться.

**Основа глагола -худать без приставки не употребляется, это просторечие.**

Приставка ИЗ / ИС  вносит значение **исчерпанности, полноты проявления действия** исхудал - весь, до конца исхудал, от него - исхудание. Исхудел, видимо, тоже было когда-то возможно, теперь стало просторечием. Ефремова относит его к разговорным.
 https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/172257/%D0%98%D1%81%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C

Так что просто изменилась продуктивность суффиксов, а значения у них одни.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ, правда, сомнения у меня остались, попробую их обозначить. 1) Мне кажется, в языке существуют два значения: похудеть (уменьшить вес, в том числе целенаправленно)  и похудать (вследствие внутреннего неконтролируемого состояния),  поэтому хорошо бы иметь разные слова для их обозначения. 2) Слишком много различных мнений у пользователей, один словарь Ефремовой их не отрегулирует. 3) Похудание ближе к медицинской терминологии.

Comment: 4) В словообразовательном словаре  есть формант ИЗ...СЯ (бегать - избегаться, страдать - исстрадаться, верить - извериться), он обозначает нежелательное состояние, связанное с интенсивностью действия. Можно сравнить: худеть - исхудеться/исхудать, то есть исхудать заменяет несуществующую форму с этим значением. А сущ. "похудание" с суффиксом А действительно соответствует глаголу "исхудать" (вместо несуществующего  "исхудания").

Comment: Ксения, это не только мнение Ефремовой. Ушаков вообще считает похудать областническим (южное, я согласна, области, близкие к Украине, тоже говорят похудать) https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Ushakov-term-54292.htm На этой же страничке Малый академич.словарь говорит, что худать/похудать-просторечие, Энциклопедический словарь - что похудать= похудеть -  разговорное, разные значения не указаны. Так что разные значения народ придаёт сам (в разговорных словах). На одном из сайтов прямо указано, что в письменной речи употреблять похудать нельзя.

Comment: Да, спасибо, просто практика использования слов очень неоднозначна, в том числе в книжных текстах.